# using a class as an attribute in python

Tags: python

I am new to python ( coming from Java world ). I have a class which has two attributes.  I need another attribute which should be an object.

How can I do that more in a pythonic way?

This is what I have tried

```
class DummyData():
    def __init__(self,lat,long):
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.data = []
loc_1 = DummyData(12,22)
my_data = {
    "mess_11" : 0.002,
    "mess_22" : 2.222,
    "mess_33" : 3.23

}

loc_1.data = my_data
```

Comment: are you asking about init parameters? Can you try to clarify your question?

Comment: DummyData.data is created as list, however, you are assigning dictionary (Java map) into it. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Please dont use () as it would make any sense. The contents of () for the class is used for inheritance.

Comment: to clarify @What comment, don't use () after the class name

Comment: @What dont know what you meant

Comment: @TheProfiler to clarify: When you define a class in python you write the class keyword followed by the class name followed by the optional classes that the class you construct inherits enclosed in brackets followed by ":". There is no need to write brackets if there is no class to inherit from. The constructor is \_\_init\_\_.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. was useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want [keyword args](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/)?

```
class DummyData:
    def __init__(self,lat,long,**kwargs):
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.data = kwargs

loc_1 = DummyData(12,22,mess_11=0.002,mess_22=2.222,mess_33=3.23)
print(loc_1.data['mess_11']) # 0.002
```

or just a dict argument?

```
class DummyData:
    def __init__(self,lat,long,dct):
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.data = dct

loc_1 = DummyData(12,22,{
    "mess_11" : 0.002,
    "mess_22" : 2.222,
    "mess_33" : 3.23
})
print(loc_1.data['mess_11']) # 0.002
```

or what else?

```
class DummyData:
    def __init__(self,lat,long,dct):
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.data = type('myobj', (), dct)

loc_1 = DummyData(12,22,{
    "mess_11" : 0.002,
    "mess_22" : 2.222,
    "mess_33" : 3.23
})
print(loc_1.data.mess_11) # 0.002
```